# I cannot draw negative y-values and positive y-values in one barchart using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Please help.. as I wrote in the issue title, I cannot draw negative y-values and positive y-values in one barchart. I use your code and only change a few line of it.

the original source is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivity.java.

the edited source is: https://db.tt/FWGvAZOZ

I only edited line 266-273.

The snippet (original):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    float mult = (range + 1);
    float val = (float) (Math.random() * mult);
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(val, i));
}
```

The snippet (edited):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    float val = (float) ((double)1.0 * (float)i) -5;
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(val, i));           
}
```

I already open an issue in the author github (issue #183), and I post here in stackoverflow, hoping here I can have faster response.

Thanks, folks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update for v3.0.0+**:

`startAtZero(...)` is deprecated, you can make use of:

```
axis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // start axis zero (min value 0f)
axis.setAxisMaximum(100f); // set axis max value to 100f
```

To modify or "lock" the range you want your axis to display. Additionally, have a look at the documentation:

- [AxisBase](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/)
- [YAxis](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/yaxis/)
- [XAxis](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/xaxis/)

Comment: I need to display negative bars too, but I can't find this method.

Comment: In the newer versions of the library, this is now set via the YAxis class

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Not able to display the Bar chart with y Axis value as Negative -30 to Positive 30 and display graph from this. Please help in this topic

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Please have a look at my issue this is serious https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

```
 // For setting negative axis for y
 BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
 chart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);
 chart.getAxisRight().setStartAtZero(false);
```

Comment: according to [the documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis#user-content-customizing-the-axis-range-min--max) `setStartAtZero` is deprecated, use `setAxisMinValue` and `setAxisMinValue` instead.

Comment: chart.setStartAtZero(false); not working for me .I am using MPchart version  compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'

Comment: chart..setStartAtZero(boolean b); Method was deprecated. Use below method instead of it.
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0);
Hope It's work for you.

Comment: @Jon Please have a look at my issue too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @HardyAndroid Please have a look at my issue too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart?answertab=votes#tab-top